# Почему этот блок Python-кода выдает такой непредсказуемый результат?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def test():
    acts = []
    for i in range(5):
        acts.append(lambda x: i ** x)
    return acts
res = test()
res[0](2) # результат: 16
res[1](2) # результат: 16
res[2](2) # результат: 16
```

Почему этот блок Python-кода выдает такой непредсказуемый результат?

Comment: А что вы ожидали?

Comment: Что append каждой новой итерации будет увеличивать значение i

Comment: Блок for не создаёт новое пространство имён, переменная i внутри test() общая для всех лямбд, и она имеет то значение, которое в неё запихали в последний раз - то есть 4

Answer (score 2):

Вы столкнулись с такой вещью, как замыкание.

Ваша анонимная функция имеет ***ссылку*** на переменную `i`, а не само значение переменной  в конкретный момент времени. Когда вы вызываете lambda, она обращается к переменной и берет ее значение. На момент окончания цикла, это всегда будет значение `4` в вашем случае.

К примеру. вот так вы всегда будете умножать на 100.

```
def test():
    acts = []
    for i in range(5):
        acts.append(lambda x: i ** x)
    i = 100
    return acts
```

Обычно, чтобы этого не происходило, нужно разорвать связь с переменной. К примеру, можно с помощью другой анонимной функции получить копию переменной, ведь в функции передаются копии для простых типов. И потом уже её использовать.

```
def test():
    acts = []
    for i in range(5):
        func = lambda y: 
            lambda x: y ** x
        acts.append(func(i)) --передали переменную как копию и разорвали связь с `i`
    return acts
res = test()
print(res[0](2), res[1](2), res[2](2), res[3](2), res[4](2))
```

В любом случае эта тема подробнее освещается в статьях/темах/главах по замыканиям closure.